# Command line tool to view and edit iTunes-specific ID3 tags

Tags: osx, command-line, mp3, id3, itunes

I'm working with podcast mp3 files, and I noticed in my KID3 ID3 tag viewer that iTunes has placed the description of the episode in a special hidden field after the standard ID3 fields. So KID3 is great, but I cannot use it as a command line tool.

The specific field in question is the "TDS" field iTunes is writing to, which is clearly the same as the "TDES" field, but none of the various applications I have tried (mutagen, eyeD3, id3v2) can read the TDS field.

Is there another application that can view non-standard ID3 tag fields that can be used in a command line context? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to my question, so I'll post it here for posterity.

Using exiftool, I was able to view hidden ID3 fields using the command 
`exiftool -b -U -ID3_TDS [filepath]`
which views the hidden field ID3_TDS and outputs their contents as a binary.

All of the other mp3 tags can be viewed by exiftool in a similar way. To see the available fields, try `exiftool -v [filepath]`